# Django - how to get needed data from multiple models

Tags: django, object, view, get, models

event = Event.objects.filter(org=request.org).select_related("event_def", "location", "space")

and i get smthing like this

1st object
Almaty nights #some event_def

inside-->Sary Arka #location

inside location-->Hall 7 #place

inside place-->3 мая 1991 г. 0:00:00 #Event

2nd object
Almaty nights #some event_def

inside-->Omega #location

inside location-->Hall 2 #place

inside place-->6 мая 1991 г. 0:00:00 #Event

i need one event_def and inside multiple locations..etc

event model

```
org = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
event_def = ChainedForeignKey(EventDef,
    chained_field = "org",
    chained_model_field = "org",
    show_all = False,
    auto_choose = True
)
location = ChainedForeignKey(Location,
    chained_field = "org",
    chained_model_field = "org",
    show_all = False,
    auto_choose = True
)
space = ChainedForeignKey(Space,
    chained_field = "location",
    chained_model_field = "location",
    show_all = False,
    auto_choose = True
)
time = models.DateTimeField()
enabled = models.IntegerField(choices = ns.FULL_ENABLE_STATUSES, default = ns.ENABLED_STATUS)
objects = EnableDisableManager()
```

Comment: Please can you post your `Event` model code here?

Comment: if org and location are variables, they should not be in quotes. Currently you are using them as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to be able to get multiple locations for an event? If you do, then your data model is wrong. For an event to have multiple locations, you want to do this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    org = ...
    event_def = ...
    space = ...
    ...

class Location(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='locations')
    ...
```

And then in your template you'll be able to do this:

```
{{ event }}
{% for location in event.locations %}
    {{ location }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you can follow just specific relations with select_related() by listing the fieldnames in the (), see the bottom of the [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) section in the docs.

Comment: no problem. It can really help cut down query times for models with lots of FK fields if you really only care about getting the related models for a couple FK fields instead.

Comment: Hi Moncler - it's good practice on Stack Overflow to post the answer you found. Answer your own question so that it might help others who find this in the future!

Comment: i used Dajax(Dajaxice) library, it's not related to this question

Comment: i can't answer to own questions,i have small reputation))